How to use a mapped class that has some attributes unmapped and has some functionality (methods)
I have the following User class. My desired behavior is when the application creates an instance of the User class that a corresponding entry in the users table will added with an id and name. When the application is booted the next time it will extract the users from the users table and recreate instance of each User automatically. When a class has all of its attributes mapped this is relatively straightforward. But in this case my class has a hash attribute (which is simply a hashed value of the name attribute) that is not mapped and it has a sayHi method (some functionality).
I was able to implement the first part of this behavior (creating the instance and saving it in the database). The second part is where I'm not sure what to do. When I retrieve the User from the database (as user) I get an object that reports to be an instance of the User class yet it wasn't fully instantiated (ie. user does not have a hash attribute and the output didn't print when it was instantiated).

So how does SQLAlchemy create this instance that reports to be an instance of the class without calling the __init__ method on the class?
And then how do I get an instance with all attributes?

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass, Mapped, mapped_column

engine = create_engine('sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
metadata_obj = MetaData()

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base, MappedAsDataclass):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.hash = hash(self.name)
        self.sayHi()
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User(name='{self.name}')>"
    
    def sayHi(self):
        print(f'{self.name} says hi')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# first part
john = User(name='John')
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(john)
    session.commit()

# second part
with Session(engine) as session:
    user = session.get(User, 1)
    print(f'user: {user.name} - type: {type(user)}')
    print(vars(user))

Output:
John says hi
user: John - type: <class '__main__.User'>
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7ebe17e60fb0>, 'id': 1, 'name': 'John'}

Python 3.12
SQLAlchemy 2.0.35

